# how to get selected table row values using jquery?

Tags: jquery, row

I need to get the selected row values in  a table using jquery by clicking on the row or a link.. i am new to jquery ,,anybody help me with sample code..that would help me greately. Thanks in advance

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Try it for yourself (otherwise you won't learn anything from the experience), and come back when you have specific issues and some actual code.

Comment: Yes, show an example of what you've tried already and what didn't work.  Don't be lazy.

Comment: Thank u all who responded to my query and i got the solution to my query ..

Answer (score 2):

See this jsFiddle snippet:

http://jsfiddle.net/hU89p/

It returns the raw text inside all of the `td`s in the clicked row. Of course, if you need something more specific, continue with jQuery / JavaScript programming to get specific cells etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
 $('#YourTableid tr').click(function (event) {
       //do your logic here
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean it:

javascript:

```
​$('table tr td a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

html:

```
​<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">2</a></td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">3</a></td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/CB9L2/)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​