# Get the selected rows from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has 10 rows and 3 columns and each row has a checkbox associated with it. The user can select any number of rows and when he presses the Submit button an alert message needs to be displayed containing the values in all the selected rows preferably as a JSON string. How do I extract all the selected rows alone and convert it to a JSON string using either Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564054/how-to-get-selected-table-row-values-using-jquery

Comment: Do you have any example code how you tried to do it? Overall it sounds really easy to "assign" a checkbox to a row.

Comment: You should show some work that you have done, some code that you have attempted. Stack Overflow as a community is here to help those who try. It is not a service to ask for ready made answers.

Comment: It depends on how the checkboxes are "associated" with the rows. Are they inside one of the cells? And when you say "the values in all the selected rows" I'm guessing you mean {row1:{col1:value1,col2:value2,col3:value3},row2:{...}} etc? Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: @name Duly noted my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I've understood your requirements well. Please consider this solution.

```js
$('#btn-table-rows').click(function (event) {
    var values = [];
    
    $('table #row-selector:checked').each(function () {
     var rowValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.row-value').text();
     values.push(rowValue)
    });
    
    var json = JSON.stringify(values);
    
    alert(json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="row-selector" type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td class="row-value">Row #1: Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="row-selector" type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td class="row-value">Row #2: World</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="btn-table-rows">Process</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted.